# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway Connection refused connecting to upstream

Tags: php, webserver

Picking up and rejuvenating an old dormant project and seeing a persistent Nginx 502 bad gateway on my Apache/Nginx development and as this was originally developed by someone else I'm struggling to find the answer.

Trying to view example.com/test gives the error. Any ideas for what I can check please?

**Nginx error.log:**

> 2017/09/07 18:20:31 [error] 11911#0: *311 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.my.ip.xx, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test", host: "www.example.com"
>
> 2017/09/07 18:20:42 [info] 11911#0: *312 client closed connection while SSL handshaking, client: xx.my.ip.xx, server: 0.0.0.0:443

**Nginx config:**

```
user  nobody;
# no need for more workers in the proxy mode
worker_processes  4;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20480;
events {
 worker_connections 5120; # increase for busier servers
 use epoll; # you should use epoll here for Linux kernels 2.6.x
}
http {

# custom start

proxy_buffering    off;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
  # proxy_http_version appeared in nginx 1.1.4
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  upstream thedevelopment {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  }

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     www.example.com domain.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen               443;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;
    keepalive_timeout    70;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.130:8080;
    }

    location /test {
      proxy_pass  http://thedevelopment;
    }
 }
# custom end

 server_name_in_redirect off;
 server_names_hash_max_size 10240;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;
 include    mime.types;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;
 server_tokens off;
# remove/commentout disable_symlinks if_not_owner;if you get Permission denied error
# disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
 sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout  5;
 gzip on;
 gzip_vary on;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
 gzip_proxied any;
 gzip_http_version 1.1;
 gzip_min_length  1000;
 gzip_comp_level  6;
 gzip_buffers  16 8k;
# You can remove image/png image/x-icon image/gif image/jpeg if you have slow CPU
 gzip_types    text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/xml image/png image/x-icon image/gif image/jpeg application/javascript application/xml+rss text/javascript application/atom+xml;
 ignore_invalid_headers on;
 client_header_timeout  3m;
 client_body_timeout 3m;
 send_timeout     3m;
 reset_timedout_connection on;
 connection_pool_size  256;
 client_header_buffer_size 256k;
 large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
 client_max_body_size 200M; 
 client_body_buffer_size 128k;
 request_pool_size  32k;
 output_buffers   4 32k;
 postpone_output  1460;
 proxy_temp_path  /tmp/nginx_proxy/;
 proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:5m max_size=1000m;
 client_body_in_file_only on;
 log_format bytes_log "$msec $bytes_sent .";
 log_format custom_microcache '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" nocache:$no_cache';
 include "/etc/nginx/vhosts/*";
}
```

Comment: run `nginx -t` and see if your nginx is even running or not? I feel config is not right here

Comment: That returns
`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`
`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: Can you do `curl -v http://thedevelopment` directly if that doesn't work then that means the service your passing the request to is not there at all

Comment: I think you've just helped me, I've found something else missing that should be there too and the curl failed. Thank you.